# Mysql how to select max id group by another id where boolean is false

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have the following table:

- PRIMARY Int id
- Int another_id
- Boolean condition

I would like to select all `max(id)` grouped by another_id but only if the `max(id)` line has the condition equals to `FALSE`.

I tried to `SELECT MAX(id) WHERE` condition `IS FALSE GROUP BY another_id`, but I got the previous id.
For example, with the following table:

```
 id | another_id | condition
 1  |         42 |         0
 2  |         42 |         1
 3  |         31 |         0
 4  |         77 |         1
```

The only result I want is `id == 3`

Is there any way to do that?

In advance, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
MAX(id)
FROM
Table1 t
GROUP BY another_id
HAVING SUM(`condition`) = 0
```

See it live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2bef7/2/0).

Answer (score 0):

Try this inline view:

```
SELECT MAX(MaxID) FROM 
(SELECT MAX(ID) AS MaxID FROM TABLE GROUP BY another_id) AS T
```